# VBA Paste below collapsed Group

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a macro that copies rows from a Sheet named "Template" and pastes them onto the Active Sheet in the next blank row.

However this macro only works when the grouped cells on the Active Sheet are expanded.
If the grouped cells are collapsed, then the macro replaces a previous collapsed group.

I have done some reading and discovered that using a different method to calculate the last row i.e. the `MergeArea` property would work with collapsed groups but just sure how to apply it.

How could I achieve this with the current code?

This is my code:

```
Sub Paste_New_Product_from_Template()
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim StartNumber As Long
    Dim varString As String
    
    '~~> This is your input sheet
    Set copySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")
 
    '~~> Variable
    varString = copySheet.Cells(2, 2).Value2
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    '~~> Initialize the start number
    StartNumber = 1
    
    With pasteSheet
        '~~> Find the last cell to write to
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) = 0 Then   
            LRow = 2
        Else
            LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            
            '~~> Find the previous number
            For i = LRow To 1 Step -1
                If .Cells(i, 2).Value2 = varString Then
                    StartNumber = .Cells(i, 6).Value2 + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End If
        
        copySheet.Range("2:" & copySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        .Rows(LRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        
        '~~> Set the start number
        .Cells(LRow, 6).Value = StartNumber

        '~~> Format the number
        .Cells(LRow, 6).Value = "'" & Format(StartNumber, "000") 
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is the code that uses the MergeArea procedure:

```
Private Function RowIsEmpty(WSh As Worksheet, Row As Long, StartColumnNumber As Integer, EndColumnNuber As Integer) As Boolean
  Dim j As Integer

  RowIsEmpty = True
  
  For j = StartColumnNumber To EndColumnNuber
    If (WSh.Cells(WSh.Cells(Row, j).MergeArea.Row, WSh.Cells(Row, j).MergeArea.Column) <> "") Then
      RowIsEmpty = False
      Exit For 'One of columns isn't empty
    End If
  Next j
End Function


Private Function CalcLastRowNumber(WSh As Worksheet, StartColumnNumber As Integer, EndColumnNuber As Integer) As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim Result As Long
  Dim Found As Boolean
  
  Result = 1
  For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If RowIsEmpty(WSh, i, StartColumnNumber, EndColumnNuber) And _
      RowIsEmpty(WSh, i + 1, StartColumnNumber, EndColumnNuber) And _
      RowIsEmpty(WSh, i + 2, StartColumnNumber, EndColumnNuber) Then
                   'Stop searching
          Exit For 'All Columns are empty for current row and for next 2 rows
    End If
    Result = i
  Next i
  CalcLastRowNumber = Result
End Function

Sub New_Reviss_Order()
```

Comment: Consider expanding your groups, adding your lines, and then collapsing it back to the state it was in before the code as run. If you use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` there will be no visible indication of what went on in the background.

Comment: I had considered this, however every group has 60 rows and there will eventually be hundred of groups. Not sure that it will be a good way to do it.

Comment: Have updated the question to show the ```MergeArea``` method of finding the last row.

Comment: When a group is collapsed the row height is reduced to zero, making it invisible to everybody, including Excel. Merging is not involved in this process. Therefore looking at MergeAreas will not help. Perhaps `xlCellTypeVisible` can be employed but I think expanding and re-collapsing will prove more efficient than alternatives.

Comment: I have just tried to use ```ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2``` ```.Rows(LRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll``` ```ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1``` and the collapsed rows are still overwritten. Is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: Also just thought I would paste the forum where I found that code. The code was posted in post #9 and post #12 seems to confirm that it works for this issue. https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1308654-how-to-have-macro-copy-and-paste-cells-below-collapsed-group.html

Comment: Also on the other idea of expanding/collapsing. It is only the Last row group that needs to be expanded to make the code work. So I was thinking if the Last Row OutlineLevel > 1 then paste, else apply the Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2 only to that last group. Is that possible?